# Initializing two LazyDataModel in postconstruct methode not working

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, lazy-loading, icefaces

I wanted to initialize 2 lazydatamodels in my init methode that have postconstruct annotation but it's not working (page keeps loading without showing any results) but when i initialize only one of them it works fine, usualy it should work fine when initializing the two of them to.

```js
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped

public class gestionAgence implements Serializable{
 /**
  * 
  */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private LazyDataModel<Agence> agences;
 private LazyDataModel<User> users;

 
 
 public gestionAgence() {
  super();
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

 @PostConstruct
 public void init() {
  agences = new agenceLazyDataModel();
  users = new userLazyDataModel();
 }
 
 public LazyDataModel<User> getUsers() {
  return users;
 }

 public void setUsers(LazyDataModel<User> users) {
  this.users = users;
 }

 public LazyDataModel<Agence> getAgences() {
  return agences;
 }

 public void setAgences(LazyDataModel<Agence> agences) {
  this.agences = agences;
 }
 
 
}
```

```js
public class userLazyDataModel extends LazyDataModel<User>{
 /**
  * 
  */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 List<User> userList;
 dao d = new dao();
 
 public userLazyDataModel()
 { userList = new ArrayList<>();
  userList = d.getUsers();
  setRowCount(userList.size());
 }
 @Override
 public List<User> load(int first, int pageSize, SortCriteria[] arg2,
   Map<String, String> arg3) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<>();

         int initial = first;

         for (int i = initial; i < initial + pageSize && i < userList.size(); i++) {
             list.add(userList.get(i));
         }

         return list;
 }

}
```

```js
public class agenceLazyDataModel extends LazyDataModel<Agence>{
 /**
  * 
  */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 List<Agence> agenceList;
 dao d = new dao();
 
 public agenceLazyDataModel()
 { agenceList = new ArrayList<>();
  agenceList = d.listeAgence();
  setRowCount(agenceList.size());
 }
 @Override
 public List<Agence> load(int first, int pageSize, SortCriteria[] arg2,
   Map<String, String> arg3) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   ArrayList<Agence> list = new ArrayList<>();

         int initial = first;

         for (int i = initial; i < initial + pageSize && i < agenceList.size(); i++) {
             list.add(agenceList.get(i));
         }

         return list;
 }

}
```

Comment: when you say  "but when i initialize only one of them it works" you mean any one of them would work? or just agenceLazyDataModel?

Comment: any one of them i tried each one on it's own and they both work

Comment: please post also agenceLazyDataModel

Comment: yes it's almost the same thing one is LazyDataModel<User> the other LazyDataModel<Agence>

Comment: when you debug it what happened? this can happened when you mix frameworks jsf, cdi spring..

Comment: i havent done any debuging to be honest i dont know how to debug

Comment: just put a breakpoint (click on the left of the lines) in the end of init method and  run on debug mode

Comment: in the variables tab it shows both the LazyDataModels as having null values